# Does a 300mbps 802.11n wireless connection have any noticeable speed improvement over 54mbps g?

Tags: wireless-networking

300mbps sounds wonderful, but not with my horrible Comcast internet connection.

I doubt there's an internet connection in America that even hits 54mbps. So I'm guessing that the only reason someone would be inclined to upgrade is for faster data transfer within the local network.

With my internet connection where download rates are rarely ever above a few hundred kilobytes a second, would I even see any improvement in switching from 802.11g to 802.11n?

Comment: In fact some corporate and university internet connections can be much faster than 54 Mb/s.

Answer (score 2):

Unless your G router is dropping packets, you won't see an overall download speed increase by going to N, as the limiting factor is your internet connection, not the speed of the router.

Across your network, you;ll see better performance, but not on downloads.

Answer (score 1):

802.11n provides a greater wireless range the G as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. the main issue with upgrading to 802.11N is you must upgrade ALLLLLL your endpoint wifi clients to 802.11n. You will drop down the the speed of your old 802.11G devices when they are active on the network.

another thing is 802.11N will stomp over other lesser networks like A B and G.  so putting your router into a mix-mode might have an ill effect for your neighbors.

as for your internet/WAN connection going faster with 802.11N, it won't your connection is only as fast as your WAN.  you will see an improvement with LAN/WLAN traffic but you will not see any difference between your WLAN to WAN speeds.  as for WAN you probally have a bunk/over used DSN server. i suggest 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4 (google)or 208.67.222.222(openDNS) you would be suprised how much faster your internet SEEMS with responsive DNS server.

Answer (score 0):

You are right with your assessment that raw speed will probably not increase other than on your local network.

While you probably won't see a raw speed increase, you will most likely see an increase in overall network performance do to the increased signal strength of Wireless N.